# Validate isNaN but allow blanks

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to perform some client-side validation on user input to make sure that all entries are numbers. (More specifically, 2 digits plus decimal.)

I understand that part, but my problem is whether I use isNaN or write a regular expression to check the format, it is picking up the blank entries as invalid.

Here is my code, you can see all the different methods that I tried to accept the blank fields that are commented out. None of them work, they all return blanks as not a number...

```
    function validateData() {
//      var re = /^\s*?/;
        $( "input" ).each(function(index) {
            if(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) === false) {
                console.log("Field " + index + " is ok"); 
//          }else if
//              ((($(this).val()).trim()) == "" ) { 
//              console.log("Field " + index + " is ok");   
//              console.log($(this).val());             
//          } else if 
//              (re.test($(this).val())) {      
//          } else if 
//              (($(this).val()).trim().isEmpty()) {            
//          } else if 
//              ((parseFloat($(this).val())).trim().isEmpty()) {    
//          } else if 
//              (($(this).text()) === "") {
//              console.log("Field " + index + " is ok"); 
            } else  {
                $("#messages").html("Please enter only numbers");
                console.log("Field " + index + " is not a number!");
            }; 
        });
    };
```

Comment: Here's what I found out. The HTML5 input type="number" validation is failing on the blank fields, so it won't run the javascript validation after it. If I take out that attribute, it runs fine. However, I like the arrows & step attribute that go along with number. Is there a way to have both?

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. Can someone tell me why there is now a -1 next to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var value = $(this).val();
if((+value == value) && !isNaN(+value)){
    //Yey we have a valid number.
}
```

This is probably one of the few valid uses of a loose equality operator I have found (it guards against null and "" being passed in). It uses the unary plus operator plus a little bit of magic and it's a nice short way of checking if a value is a number or not.

Your code should now look like:

```
   function validateData() {
        $( "input" ).each(function(index) {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if((+value == value) && !isNaN(+value)){
               //The value is a valid number
            } else {
               //The value is NOT a valid number
            }
        });
    };
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8zjpfzx/2/

Comment: The validation now allows for blank spaces but it says that all other letters & characters are ok too... I'm not sure why this is so hard but I think it is because I am collecting all the data from the form with each & I'm messing up somewhere in there.

Comment: Can you give me an example of one that fails?

Comment: Any letters I enter don't catch as invalid. Could the problem be elsewhere in my code? Everything else is in php & this is the only js on the page....

Comment: Check it in console. e.g. (+"abc"== "abc") && !isNaN(+"abc") is false so the logic should work

Comment: This fixed the problem...except in Chrome for some reason. It works great in IE & Firefox but for some reason doesn't throw an error if I enter letters in Chrome (which could have been the case all along, as I wasn't testing anywhere else.) That will work for my purposes though because I have some HTML5 validation in place too & that works in Chrome but not IE. Any idea what could cause this not to work in Chrome? I disabled the cache...?

Comment: Odd as I am using it in chrome right now for testing and it seems to work (well the logic of the if statement works in any case).

Comment: We finally figured it out!! The reason that it didn't work in Chrome is because I have some HTML5 validation in place on the form. The HTML5 validation will always run first (if browser recognizes HTML5) & if anything fails, it will not run the jquery validation. If I set the form attribute to 'novalidate', then my jquery runs as it should :)

Comment: @heat222 You might want to look at something called http://modernizr.com/. I would use that and let the html5 form validation do its thing if it has the ability to do so but then fall back to jquery if it can't. That way you are future proofing your app.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with your regex, try to use the following `/[\d\s]+/` :

```
$( "input" ).each(function(index) {
  var patt = new RegExp("/[\d\s]+/");
  var res = patt.test($(this).val());
  if(res){
    console.log("Field " + index + " is ok");
  }else{
    console.log("Field " + index + " is not ok");
  }
})
```

> \d match a digit [0-9]
>
> \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

See this [**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/hK4jK9/1).

Comment: Thank you for the demo. Your suggestion worked too. Apparently,my problem is because I have both HTML5 validation & jquery validation. The HTML5 validation runs first & if something fails, it never hits my jquery validation.

Answer (score 0):

Change line
`if(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) === false)`
to:
`if(isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) === false || $(this).val() === '')`

Comment: I tried this one & it now says blanks spaces are ok but it also now allows letters & other characters that I don't want to allow.

Comment: This worked too. I found my issue lies in my browser. For some reason, my validation isn't catching errors in Chrome, but seems to work fine in all other browsers. Thanks for the help :)